# Log4Net works on VisualStudio Debug/Release, but not after deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, log4net

In order to make more complex logs, I've decided to use the Log4Net for my WPF desktop app. It works perfectly, creating both 'Debug' messages at the 'Output' and writes to a file all the logs...

BUT if I deploy it/install it (using visual studio's wizard to create a .MSI setup) it stops working. I can't find any file on the folder or anywhere on the computer related to it.

I'm using Caliburn.Micro to organize my code. And in order to have the logs, I 'centralized' it by using a public static class by the name of "Logging.cs".

The code inside "Initialize()" was put right now as a way to try out, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
public static class Logging
{

    //Declaration of the logger
    /// <summary>
    /// Logger for the Logging manager.
    /// </summary>
    private static log4net.ILog Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


    public static void Initialize()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a log in Fatal level accompanied by an expection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    /// <param name="error">Exception thrown along with the log</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void Fatal(string message, Exception error, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Fatal(message, error);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a log in Fatal level
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void Fatal(string message, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Fatal(message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a log in Error level accompanied by an expection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    /// <param name="error">Exception thrown along with the log</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void Error(string message, Exception error, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Error(message, error);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a log in Error level
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void Error(string message, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Error(message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a log in Warn level accompanied by an expection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    /// <param name="error">Exception thrown along with the log</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void Warn(string message, Exception error, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Warn(message, error);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a log in Warn level
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void Warn(string message, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Warn(message);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a log in Info level accompanied by an expection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    /// <param name="error">Exception thrown along with the log</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void Info(string message, Exception error, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Info(message, error);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a log in Info level
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void Info(string message, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Info(message);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a log in Debug level accompanied by an expection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    /// <param name="error">Exception thrown along with the log</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void Debug(string message, Exception error, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Debug(message, error);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a log in Debug level
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void Debug(string message, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Debug(message);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Log created in Debug level containing not only a log message but also an object to be serialized and logged.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged (should be description of object)</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Object to be displayed</param>
    /// <param name="senderType">From where the log comes from</param>
    public static void ShowObject(string message, object obj, Type senderType)
    {
        //Defines 'type' in the log.
        Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(senderType);
        Logger.Debug(message + "\n<object>" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj) + "</object>\n");
    }
}
```

Also, here is my log4net config file:

```
    <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="console" />
      <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
    <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - [%message] // %exception%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="DesktopApp.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - [%message] // %exception%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
  </log4net>
```

And at the AssemblyInfo.cs, I've merely inserted this at the end:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true,ConfigFile ="log4net.config")]
```

Thank you for your time, please comment if I can add any more details.

P.S.: The software is installed inside the AppData, so no file permission issues should arise, since I am using another framework to automatically update the app.

P.S.2: I used DebugView and in the middle of mostly info that seemed random I've found an error:

```
[5480] log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

Still haven't tried fixing it, just keeping this question up to date. (Thanks Varun!)

Comment: Is there a reason that DesktopApp.log would not be able to be created on the target machine?

Comment: The software is installed at the Appdata's Local folder, so no permission/file writing issue should arise. I was using a "manual" log previously and it worked smoothly.

Comment: You can debug whats going on internally with log4net.It might give you some insight Follow this link - https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug

Comment: Thank you. Will be checking it out. I'll update if I find anything new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I was looking at the wrong place all this time. When I checked the instalation folder, I noticed there was no log4net.config! ... This is why it worked well during debug (because the config was there) but not after deployment!

Sorry for the bother and thank you for all the help.

Comment: Had made the same mistake. Got here while googling for it and found your note, thanks dude! :)